# How to maintain my data like a session variable in .NET Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using .NET Windows Forms. I need to maintain some date to check the condition. So I have to maintain it until the user logs out.

Like session in ASP.NET.

How can I do this? (Note it should not expire until the user logs out.)

#### Update:

I create Namespace like this

> namespace nsGlobalData 
>   {
>
> class GlobalData
>
> ```
> {
>
>     public static int GlobalOrgId;
>
>  }
> ```
>
> }

To Set:

> GlobalData.GlobalOrgId = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[1].Rows[0].ItemArray[0]);

ToGet

> txtnamt.text=GlobalData.GlobalOrgId;

Comment: windows form application is statefull, so you need not worry about maintaining state.

Comment: @vilx: Win form app is statefull (compared to web forms). State per form  shouldn't be an issue. For multiple forms a single static class (with decent thread safety)should do. Well that's what i meant.

Comment: @PRR - I know it, and you know it, but do you think the OP understood it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    internal static Dictionary<string, object> GlobalVariables = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a static variable in some class?

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan - then make the static variable a list of values, or have a few of them